# Need to grep file with specific letter and move to another folder Linux

Tags: command-line, grep, filenames

I need to select files which contain "Error" or "traffic" in their names, e.g.

```
abc_ERRor.csv
raError.csv
bsn_Error.csv
bbbctraffic.csv
ccc_traffic.csv
...
```

and move them into corresponding directories like `Error_directory` and 
`traffic_directory` according to their names.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
mv $(ls test_file | grep -l 'Error>' *) Error_directory
```

How can I do this from the command-line?

```
ls test_file | grep 'Error'
```

Comment: `grep` is irrelevant here.  Start with the task, and then determine the tools, and try to avoid using Unix commands as verbs unless that is *exactly* what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

Parsing the output of `ls` is rarely a good idea due to the wide range of characters that can occur in file names. A better solution might be:

```
find ./test_file -iname "*error*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} Error_directory
```

Notice the `-iname` option. This will return case insensitive matches, allowing you to find and move files such as:

```
abc_ERRor.csv
error_123.csv
ErRoR_77.csv
```

If you don't need your search to be case insensitive, something as simple as this should suffice:

```
mv test_file/*Error* Error_directory
```

Further reading:

[xargs separator problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem)

[bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the error in attempting to use `ls`, but piping `find` directly to `xargs` isn't any safer.  Use `find -print0 | xargs -0` OR `find ... -exec` instead.  Shell globs are usually the best way to go, if possible.

Comment: @jw013: Thanks, good spot. I added some resources for anyone interested in avoiding these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```
#!/bin/sh

err_dir=~/errors
tra_dir=~/traffic

for f in *.csv; do
    case $f in
        *[Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr]*) mv -i $f $err_dir ;;
        *[Tt][Rr][Aa][Ff][Ii][Cc]*) mv -i $f $tra_dir ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: You could get away with just `sh` since no `bash`-specific features were used or required in this snippet.  Also, for future reference, [`case` doesn't do word splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) so you don't need the double quotes around `$f`.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks for the reminder. Is there a way to use regular expression instead of globs in case statements?

Comment: POSIX `sh` doesn't do regex in `case` or anywhere else that I know of, and `bash` doesn't in `case` AFAIK.  Usually globs are sufficient but if you require regex you might have to go with a fancier shell or `find`.  In this particular case regular expressions are overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use find:

`find test_file -type f -name "*Error*" -exec mv {} Error_directory/ \;`

where `-type f` denotes that you are looking for files, `-name` states that you are matching on the pattern given. `exec` runs the following command, with the `{}` taking the place of files that match the parameters given to find.

If you want to use bash and do something more along the lines of what you've tried, a loop should do the trick:

```
for f in `ls test_file | grep 'Error'; do
  mv test_file/${f} Error_directory
done
```

In both examples, I've assumed test_file is a directory containing the files you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep Error | xargs -I % mv % error-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for fn in *.*; do for word in Error traffic; do echo "$fn" | grep -i "$word" && mkdir -p "$word"_directory && mv "$fn" "$word"_directory; done; done
```